# Dashboards in Google Apps Script not rendering correctly in IE?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

is there a known issue with Dashboards in Google Apps Script not rendering correctly in IE? I have embedded the Dashboard App Script on a page in google sites. It renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the charts and filters / selectors do not look correct.

Comment: As a general observation, Apps Scripts web apps don't work the same on IE and Firefox.

Comment: Do the charts rendered by the Charts API directly look fine? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls

Answer (score 0):

I can verify this as well. My [dashboard](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUootM9U5uXo_hcFD3GZXX5RHSOhMN6JvJxfnem2uRg4p78MU/exec) is not rendering properly on IE v9.0.8112.16421 - some filters and charts will appear and disappear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

We use Chrome and IE8 (and I think it's permanently in quirks mode) at work, so I have this line to make IE8 render better:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
//Will be true if the browser is IE8, false otherwise
app.setStandardsMode((UiApp.getUserAgent().indexOf("MSIE 8.0") > -1));
```

Try standards mode in different browsers, and set it to true as necessary.