# UIApp display with IE9 default to standards mode instead of quirks mode?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been informed by my users that my application is not working anymore on IE9 and after investigations I believe the culprit is the **UiApp displays** mode which should be by default set to **quirks**.

When my UiApp forms opens in IE9 they render in **standard** mode, **EVEN** if I force the mode to **quirks** via the method **setStandardsMode(false)**. On all other browsers everything renders as expected (Chrome, Firefox, Safari...).

```
// My default call to create my UiApp Application
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(400).setHeight(350);
```

Since I am using OSX Chrome, I did not noticed the problem, only when it was reported to me by a Windows user using IE9. So I do not have a precise date when this bug started. But I know 100% that this is recent, before IE9 was rendering correctly.

Are you aware of any changes made to UiApp recently that would default the UiApp Displays mode to Standart instead of Quirks?

Also seems a bug that **setStandardsMode(false)** to force to **quirks** mode do not works with IE9.

Any hint will be appreciated.

[image: IE9]

[image: Example]

Comment: recently some of the UiApp elements got depracated, as stated in the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset "Docs"). I'm not sure however if this is the reason your app serves different in IE9

Comment: [A similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897459/dashboards-in-google-apps-script-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie) was active a while ago. One comment there from a googler asked about how the Charts API examples rendered - right now, in IE9, they are a mess. They were OK in January, I know I was referencing them in IE9 at that time. Possibly related to what you're seeing.

Comment: I am not using any of the deprecated functions. Furthermore the deprecated functions and components will work until September 9, 2013. [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2013/03/retiring-a-few-apps-script-components.html)

Comment: Any chance you are zoomed in at a different level in IE?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an actual bug in UI rendering. Can you open up a bug on the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) with all the details and a small set of code for reproduction.